# How can I combine addr:* tags in JOSM to create the addr:full tag?

Tags: openstreetmap, address, conflation, josm

I have about 400 addresses that I need to update in OSM.  They have already been conflated using Josh Doe's Conflation plugin, http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Plugins/Conflation, which my version of JOSM no longer supports for some reason.  I have updated the **addr:street:name** and **addr:street:type** for the dataset in JOSM, but now I need to update the **addr:full** tag.  Is there a way to perform a calculation in JOSM that would concatenate something like this:

**addr:full** = **"addr:housenumber"** + **"addr:street:name"** + **"addr:street:type"**

If there is a way in iD, Potlatch2 or Merkaartor that would be great too.

Answer (score 2):

The `addr:full` tag is for addresses that cannot be described with the other `addr:*` tags. If the other tags are present, this tag generally should not be.

Additionally, if you need combine the housenumber and street, you should be using the standard `addr:street` tag, which is how the street name is mapped.

Are you intending to upload the results to OSM? If so, it sounds like it's a mechanical edit or an import, which means you need to consult with the appropriate community.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  What we are trying to do is change the street name within the addr:full tag in OSM.  We had to change the name of a street as we had it incorrect in our county's address database that we used to conflate with the buildings in OSM.  It sounds like the addr:full tag is unnecessary if we already have the addr:housenumber, addr:street:name, and addr:street:type tags.  If we have those tags do we still need the addr:street tag?

Comment: addr:street:name and addr:street:type are not standard tags and not consumed by anything. addr:street is the tag used to indicate the street.